# What are these extra wires coming out of my ferrite rod antenna

Tags: antenna, ferrite

From my understanding a ferrite rod antenna is simply a length of wire wrapped around a ferrite rod. A wire will sticks out of each side of the rod, one is ground and one is the main receiver.

I opened up a few radios recently and one has 4 wires coming out of the rod and one has 3.
What are these extra wires for?

Here is an image of the rods:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These *are* antennas, and at the same time they are inductors intended to be tuned with a variable capacitor, allowing one station to be selected in favour of others.

These inductors often send their output to a transistor amplifier or transistor mixer, so impedance matching is beneficial. This matching can be done a few different ways:

- a tapped inductor
- a link winding having fewer turns than the main winding

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Ezjz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>